# How to migrate gae app to python 2.7.11

Tags: google-app-engine-python

I'm getting emails from google that I should migrate my gae apps from python 2.7 to python 2.7.11. But I can't find any example how to do it. Do you know how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're receiving communications about [Python SSL Version 2.7 Shutdown](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/python-ssl-27) and the necessary migration to SSL version 2.7.11. You'll find more information in the link above but basically the migration involves:

1. Updating to the latest Cloud SDK version via `gcloud components update`.
2. Updating the app.yaml for all versions of your application
3. Deploying your updated application